# Automatically detecting Image and Video Files for further processing

Tags: python, opencv, path

So I want to write a script which I only give a path to either a folder or a file, and it will then detect all video and image files and put them in a list of videos and a list of images. For each video I'll edit the frames and produce an output video. Then I'll do the same with all images. But what is the best way to determine whether a file is a valid image or video? Or do I have to do something like this:

```
# if os.path.isdir(path_to_folder)
video_list = []
image_list = []
for file in os.listdir(path_to_folder):
  try:
    cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    video_list.append(file)
    continue
  except:
    pass

  try:
    cv2.imread(file)
    image_list.append(file)
    continue
  except:
    pass
```

I really hope there's a better way to do this. I didn't even test this code, it's so sloppy I'd prefer not to have to resort to this method.

Comment: you can check the extensions of the file and then decide

Comment: @Jeru Luke:but the extensions can be anything and don't even have to be true right? Also I don't really want to make a list of all possible image and video extensions, just to check whether I am dealing with either an image or a video. Is my idea here really the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library available just for this purpose. It surely will simplify the task.

Install the library **filetype** from [HERE](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/) which can be easily installed using `pip`. The list of supported file types are also mentioned.

```
import filetype
file = filetype.guess(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\car.png')
if file is None:
    print('Cannot guess file type!')

elif:
    print('File extension: %s' % file.extension)
    print('File MIME type: %s' % file.mime)
```

I passed in a `.png` file which resulted in:

```
File extension: png
File MIME type: image/png
```

Using the `mime` attribute you can determine what type your file is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That package even provides image and video matches. All I gotta do is import it and do `filetype.image(pathtofile)`. Thanks!