# How to get openCV to save the changes it makes to a video

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a program that resizes all videos from 448x800 to 480x640 in a set of directories, but for some reason OpenCV doesn't follow through with the changes despite throwing no errors. I'm using OpenCV 4.1.0 and Python 3.7. When I run mediainfo on the individual files, the resolution appears the same. I'm running it on Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

From what I can tell from print statements, it resizes the individual frames well enough, but the issue comes with actually saving the finished video.

```py
import cv2
import os

dirs = ['group 3','group 4','group 5','group 6','group 7','group 8']

#cycles through the directories
for i in dirs:
    files = os.listdir(i)
    print (i)
    #cycles through the files in each directory
    for j in files:
        if j.endswith('.avi'):
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i + '/' + j)
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
            out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 15, (640, 480))
            while True:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if ret==True:
                    print(frame.shape)
                    b = cv2.resize(frame, (640,480), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                    out.write(b)
                    print(b.shape)
                else:
                    break
            cap.release()
            out.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This throws no errors, but doesn't actually change the files. Any thoughts? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I guess, this is going to overwrite each video file into a single file `output.avi`  with `640X480` resolution.

Comment: Yeah that does it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 15, (640, 480))` defines a video writer that will write into a file called `output.avi` in your working directory. Since you always use the same filename the result will be the last found video, resized.

To fix this simply change the above line to:
`out = cv2.VideoWriter(j.replace(".avi", "_resized.avi", fourcc, 15, (640, 480))`

Will then get filenames like `myvideo_resized.avi`, where "myvideo" is an example for the old filename.

Also if you want to correcly check whether a file is a video file, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440023/6301103).

HTH